# Getting error while uploading file using multer

Tags: node.js, upload, multer

I am a beginner learning MERN stack and watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BnTHapJmD0&list=PL8p2I9GklV456iofeMKReMTvWLr7Ki9At&index=44 to upload file using using multer.

'''

```
const express=require("express");
const multer=require("multer");
const app=express();

const upload=multer({
    storage:multer.diskStorage({
        destination:function(req,file,cb)
        {
            cb(null,"uploads")
        },
        filename:function(req,file,cb)
        {
            cb(null,file.fieldname+"-"+Date.now()+".png")
        }

    })
}).single("user_file");
app.post("/upload",upload,(req,resp)=>{
    resp.send("File upload");
});
app.listen(5000);
```

'''
Above is my code, I have installed multer successfully.After trying to upload file from postman.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\node_tut\uploads\user_file.png'

I am constantly getting this error for any type of file. Please tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I do like this and it works

```
const storage= multer.diskStorage({
destination:function(req,file,cb)
{
        cb(null,path.join(__dirname,'../public/userImages'),function(error,success){
            if(error)throw error
        });
    },
     filename:function(req,file,cb){
         const name=Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname;
         cb(null,name,function(error1,success1){
             if(error1)throw error1
         })
     }
 });
 const upload=multer({storage:storage});

app.post("/upload",upload.single('image'),(req,resp)=>{
    resp.send("File upload");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, path.join(__dirname,'../public/images'));
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const timeStamp = moment().format('x');
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    const name = path.basename(file.originalname, ext);
    const fileName = `${name}_${timeStamp}${ext}`;
    callback(null, fileName);
  }
});
const fileUploader = multer({ storage });

app.post(
  "/upload",
  fileUploader.single('image'),
  (req,res) => {
    ...
});
```